# 16.04 Lexmark E210 printer failure

Tags: printing

Sometimes the Lexamark E210 printer does not respond or it will spool up and not print.  I  tried:

1. bouncing printer power (sometimes successful)
2. clicked the "Print Test Page button

The printer spooled up as expected to print a page, but it failed to print.

I am unable to find the print queue and seek guidance regarding diagnostic techniques and tools: thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 2 wireless printers. I found I had to reserve the URLs in the router to get them to work consistently. Evidently, Ubuntu uses a static URL to access a wireless printer and cannot do so if the router is changing it every time you turn it on which it will do if you turn other wireless devices on or off. Sometimes the router will assign the correct URL by luck, but when it doesn't,  the print que will give you a "cannot obtain printer status".

Comment: I think you really mean "host name" or "IP address" instead of "URL".